# Alert showing html code as text in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

This code works fine for Ionic 3 but in Ionic 4 beta 12, still not working. Is this a bug? should I report it? how? I read the beta doc and it doesn’t say anything of configuring how to render the text as html or not.

```
async showRules() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Rules',
      subHeader: `<!--<div class="padding">-->




Brain Builder is up to date with the most recent research regarding IQ enhancement.
As the most recent research suggest, Brain Builder will increase the number of stimulus first (position, audio, color, etc.).
Once all stimuli have been mastered, the n-back will be increased.




    <h3 class="title">
        <center>
Rules for beginners
        </center>
    </h3>


    <p>
A blue square will be shown every three seconds, press the button ‘Position’ when you find that the actual position of the blue square matches with that of the previous one.
The position of the square is accompanied with the pronunciation of a number and the very same rule applies for the sound.
    </p>

`,
      buttons: ['OK'],
      backdropDismiss: false
    });
    await alert.present();
  }
```

[image]

Comment: You inserted huge text and html into subHeader. You should have used message instead

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see an open issue for this in the `[Ionic Project Issues Section][1]`

I recommend creating an issue there and monitoring it until Ionic 4 is out of Beta and in Production.

This is the link to create an Ionic Bug Report

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/new?template=bug_report.md

Happy Coding!

-Troy

Comment: can you please post the link to open a issue?